# How to create a value of a simple type using new syntax's VALUE keyword?

Tags: abap

Here is a one for you.

It is possible to create an initial value with `VALUE` sentence.

```
DATA(l_value) = VALUE char4( ).
```

But it does not seem to be possible to create a concrete one using the same approach.

```
DATA(l_value) = VALUE char4( 'AAA' ).
```

I am getting the following syntax error.

> The type "C" is not a structure.

Any hints? How can I create a value of a simple type using `VALUE` keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.
The [documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenconstructor_expression_value.htm) explicitly specifies that

> Elementary data types and reference types **cannot be** specified explicitly with VALUE for constructing values, **except when an initial value is created.**

So the only correct use-case for using `VALUE` with elementary data types is assigning initial value. For assigning concrete value you must use `NEW` operator:

```
DATA(l_value) = NEW char4( 'AAA' ).
```

Though, it will be an object, not variable.

Comment: Hey, suncatcher. You still have time too look once again over my reduced table subset ?

Comment: @icbytes, I told you in comments that I have no idea about the reasons. And I recommended you to make extensive test on common datasets rather than those odd QM BAPI structures you quoted.

Comment: That's not a reason to get loud. But You always have to stick as close to sap standard, regardless how old some structures may be, as long there are no better options or as long reinventing thr wheel in customer namespace consumes time.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel can be very interesting if it's paid by your customer:) But commonly productive solutions should be sustainable, flexible and agile. I have no idea how is your structure populated, what collation it has, and so on and so forth. All these factors affects how table expressions behave themselves, therefore I cannot reproduce the issue. Ask further in your own question as this is offtop here.

Answer (score -1):

I am not able to understand your question clearly but if you want to give an initial value to any variable while you are declaring it then you can use 'value' keyword.

data l_value type c value 'A'.

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way. It is about the `VALUE` keyword in the new ABAP syntax.